# Element type "Resource" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, tomcat

Here is my code. I don't understand why it has error Element type "Resource" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Ex">

<Resource　name="WebTestDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container" 
           driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
           url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Student"
           username="sa" password="123456" />

</Context>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an XML closing tag at the end?

Comment: _Technique:_ Restart small with `<Resource name="WebTestDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"/>` (mind no tab char afer Resource), and add ever more attributes till you find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy pasted your XML and it broke my XML formatter tool.
It seems you have a special character that is not a regular space after :

```
<Resource name...
         ^ invalid character here
```

**Edit**: it seems to be an [ideographic space](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/12288).
I used this Java code to find out :

```
String s = "<Resource　";
s.chars().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

```
...
99    // c
101   // e
12288 // ideographic space (must be 32 for a regular space)
```

Comment: Alternative to find that out: use my Unicode Explorer. Just paste the text into the text box at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer and you'll see the U+3000.